# Understanding Alpha Beta Pruning: Why do we ignore the values of a unsearched tree after the first leaf, can they not include acceptable values too?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, search-algorithms

So this is my question.

I am trying to understand this part of the book:

[image]

At d) why do we stop looking at the other nodes in that branch? There could be a acceptable value next to the 2? I am just trying to understand alpha beta pruning for a while.

Answer (score 1):

At $d)$, minimizer is comparing the $2$ he found with the currently best option for the maximizer higher in the tree (at node $A$, where maximizer will choose between $B$,$C$,...), which is $3$, at node $B$. He then knows that maximizer will not choose $C$.

The node $C$ **will** have value $2$ when minimizer sets it and **would** have value $2$ or less if minimizer explored it fully, so he doesn't need to waste his time searching other branches from $C$ if he already knows that maximizer will not choose anything lower than $3$.

I think what confuses you may be the following:
You are imagining a real-life gameplay scenario, but this is different in the sense that minimizer and maximizer **must** play their best move and **will** calculate it correctly.
So there is no way that minimizer could in this situation "fool" maximizer by setting the wrong value of $C$ (something higher than $3$) to force maximizer to choose it. If we assume that scenario a possibility, we must also implement the maximizer with "free-will" so he may not choose his best option but this is no longer an $\alpha$-$\beta$ pruning :)

Comment: My gripe is that, the second branch (one with ptuning) might have a value greater than 2? Anyway thanks for the answer, I guess the point is, that even if there is a number less than 2, it will not be chosen by the maximizer.

Comment: Yes, exactly. And if there is a value greater than 2 (better for maximizer), minimizer must not choose it because it is not his best option (and he is the one choosing at node C).